# Android 11 - How to redirect input to external display using uinput?

Tags: android, android-11

I have virtual keyboards, touchscreen, mouse created with the help of writing the events to /dev/uinput file which injects the user events to primary display, currently trying to
inject the user events to external display? Is it possible to inject the events to external display via uinput?  Or is there any other way to inject events to external display other than uinput?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly /dev/uinput works but injecting any input event is possible via Android's Input Manager's injectInputEvent API and the InputEvent class' setDisplay method.